# Recover RAID/LVM disks from Crash-Reinstall

Tags: raid, lvm, mdadm

I had a Kubuntu system, probably 12-04, with / on an SSD and /usr and /home on separate partitions on 4 1TB hard disks, with the partitions RAIDed together.

I've just brought the system back up, the base cause seems to have been that the SSD had crashed. The system now has a new motherboard as well as a new SSD.

I've installed Kubuntu 14-04, 64bit on it, currently with everything on the SSD. The KDE partition manager shows the 4 hard disks and their partitions with 2 partitions on each drive marked as RAID.

Is there any way to recover these drives without losing the data?

Using mdadm to look at the partitions I get:

```
  /sda3 is device 0 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdb3 is device 3 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdc3 is device 1 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdd3 is device 2 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array

  /sda2 is device 0 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdb2 is device 3 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdc2 is device 1 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
  /sdd2 is device 2 in 4 device unknown raid 5 array
```

I haven't been able to figure out what steps I need to go through to re-assemble the two raid 5 arrays.

If I give:

```
mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3
```

mdadm puts /dev/sda3 into /dev/md0 as an inactive array, and I can't seem to add the other devices to /dev/md0. So there is something that I'm still missing.